# SonarQube change issue effort

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm looking into using SQ to track TechDebt/CodeSmells in our c# projects.

I've made a roslyn analyzer that looks for e.g.  `[TechDebt(Smell.IndecentExposure,...)]` attributes, and this works well using the SQ roslyn sdk. However the only options for the rules in SQALE are `CONSTANT_ISSUE` and `LINEAR`, whereas the effort for these items usually needs to be reviewed and can be different for each issue, rather than being fixed or depenant on the number of lines of code.

I can't find any way to change the issue effort on the server after a scan, and [I don't see any actions for it in here either](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/cd45a1067c9f249f9fd3e28a4f4fb957c846906a/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/issue/ws).

Is adding a `changeEffortAction` similar to the `changeSeverityAction` the simplist thing for me to do?  I'm looking at `ScannerReport.Issue.getGap()` too, possibly can hack the scanner output to put a value there originating from the attribute?

Is there a quicker way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: What SonarQube version do you use?

Comment: I think it’s 6.7.1, I just did ‘docker pull sonarqube’

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no provisions for updating effort post-analysis. Remediation costs are estimated on an "average developer, average day" basis.

Comment: Thanks Ann, I’m adding rules where the issues raised like “bad design” have effort based on cognitive input, so can’t really be derived from an analysis.  I can’t have them in the product backlog, sq seemed like a sensible option. https://github.com/flavourous/TechDebt.Compat.SonarQube I’ve got Seth that works though.